# How to allign two RelativeLayouts

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Ok so i have a ListView with some items in it and each item is custom formatted with a `LinearLayout` that contains two `RelativeLayout` items. The first one (to the left) contains a title and a subtitle of a show, and the right one contains the time the show starts, or if it's past that time it shows "MISSED".

I want the right layouts width to wrap it's content and the left layouts width to fill up the remaining space, and nothing more. When it fills the remaining space, if the title is longer than what's available i want it to go to the next line.

Right now i did a quick fix for this by making the left layouts width static, but i want it to change automatically. How can i achieve this?

This is how my XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listRoot"
    android:background="#fff">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/mainInfoPan"
        >

        <!-- TITLE -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Space Holder"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/naslov"
            android:textColor="#ff777777"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mainInfoPan"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:text="Space Holder"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#888"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where is your `LinearLayout` ?? You are using `RelativeLayout` instead.

Comment: Oh right, i was messing around and changing things. Edited the post, but the same problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by getting rid of those `RelativeLayout`'s and add some weighting. I cleaned up your code a bit.

If you aren't getting the results you wish, please edit your question as It's quite unclear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/listRoot"
    android:background="#fff">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/mainInfoPan"
        >

        <!-- TITLE -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Space Holder"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/naslov"
            android:textColor="#ff777777"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:text="Space Holder"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#888"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Oh that worked, thanks! One question tough, if I understand weight correctly it shows the ratio between views. But here you only used weight on the first layout and not on the second. Why?

Comment: You can use weights as flexible containers. So, for example: If you have an `ImageView` that's a specific width in `dp`, you can have a sibling view expand/contract to respond to that size with weights. Weights are essentially ratio's, since I only used one weight, that `LinearLayout` will use 100% of the empty space within its container. Hope this helps, gimme a check if you would! :)

Comment: NP matey, anytime. :)

Comment: Why do you use a LinearLayout with just a TextView in it?

Comment: I swapped out his `RelativeLayout`. I also have a habit of parenting my controls with `ViewGroup`'s, it just helps me visualize it better.

Comment: It also hurts performance pretty badly, considering that you're using this on an item that is shown many times.
In my answer below I show you how to use a single RelativeLayout with 3 TextView.

Comment: It actually wouldn't hurt performance that much, these are being generated by a `ListView`, which will only cache a few extra rows than the ones visible on the screen before it recycles them. Even if you had thousands of rows.

Answer (score 1):

for automatic sizes you can use the "weight" attribute.
the weight attribute divides the remaining space by % and each view get % of it

```
android:layout_height ="0dip"

android:layout_weight ="0.7"   => this view will get 70% of the available space
```

also what happend when you use "wrap_content" with the right layouts
and "fill_parent" with the left layout?

Comment: the left layout fills all of the space and the right layout is invisible. Also, AndroidStudio reports an error on the Linear layout: `Wrong orientation? No orientation specified, and the default is horizontal, yet this layout has multiple children, where at least one has layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: I will try with weight and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single RelativeLayout, with no children layouts, set the time/missed textview to

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

The use on title:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/date"
```

and on subtitle:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/title"
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/date"
```

This way you have a flat hierarchy with only 3 views in it. You can also use a fixed width for date, so all items will be aligned:

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/date_width"
```